# Play video in VLC using python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, video, vlc

I am using windows 10 64-bit system. I want to play a video in vlc media player using python2.7. I have implemented this code:
    import subprocess
    import os

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","F:/abacus.mp4"])
```

But on executing the above code, only vlc player get started but does not play that abacus.mp4 video.
I have also tried this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join("C:/", "Program   Files", "VideoLAN", "VLC", "vlc.exe"),os.path.join("F:/", "abacus.mp4")])
```

But unfortunately, I am getting the same result. Please let me know if anyone could help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use `os` module and use its `popen`?

This works for me:

```
    import os
    os.popen("C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe F:/abacus.mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But its not working for me. When I run from cmd, Its gets executed without any errors , but nothing happens after that, I mean vlc does not pops up play the required video. And when I run from pythonWin, it is showing the following error:

Comment: <open file 'C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe F:/abacus.mp4', mode 'r' at 0x02CC5180>

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as follows :-

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\\Program   Files\\\VideoLAN\\\VLC\\\vlc.exe","F:\\\abacus.mp4"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (for a different but related case):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/ProgramFiles/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","file:///F:/abacus.mp4])
```

Hope it helps.